# cg-busy on consecutive promises

Tags: angularjs, angular-promise

I have a factory which stores and periodically updates some data using a service($http call). I want the busy indicator in the view every time the data is being updated. The factory exposes the data object and the promise.

```
angular.module('myUI')
  .factory('statusFactory', function ($timeout, statusService) {
    var promise = {};
    var data = {};

    function update(){
        angular.extend(promise, statusService.status().$promise).then(function(response){
            angular.extend(data, response);
        });
        $timeout(update, 10000);
    }
    update();

    return{
        data: data,
        promise: promise
    }
});
```

In the controller, I bind these variables to scope:

```
  $scope.statusPromise = statusFactory.promise;
  $scope.data = statusFactory.data;
```

And finally in the view I present the data

```
<div cg-busy="statusPromise">
    {{data.var1}}
    {{data.var2}}
    ...
</div>
```

Now the data is being updated flawlessly, but cg-busy does nothing. I would expect the busy icon every time the $http call is being resolved. It works when I use the statusService directly in the controller.

Is there some better way to do it? How can I expose some persistent promise from the factory so that it updates view on every new call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try something like this:

```
angular.module('myUI')
  .factory('statusFactory', function ($timeout, statusService) {
    var promise = {};
    var data = {};
    var busyIndicator = {busy: false};

    function update(){
        busyIndicator.busy = true;
        angular.extend(promise, statusService.status().$promise).then(function(response){
            angular.extend(data, response);
            busyIndicator.busy = false;
        });
        $timeout(update, 10000);
    }
    update();

    return{
        data: data,
        promise: promise
    }
});
```

Bind it to `$scope`:

```
$scope.busyIndicator= statusFactory.busyIndicator;
```

And then bind it to `cg-busy` (I presume it takes `true` or `false`):

```
<div cg-busy="busyIndicator.busy">
    {{data.var1}}
    {{data.var2}}
    ...
</div>
```

`busy` needs to be used inside `busyIndicator` object, to share a reference between factory and view. Also, check if `cg-busy` is working at all, with hard-coded `true` value.